# How to cover the thumbnail of an iframe video 100% to the wrapper in 9:16 aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am using an iframe tag to play a 9:16 aspect ratio video from my google drive. The iframe is wrapped around a div and the div is styled so that there are no black bars. The video is maintaining its aspect ratio but the thumbnail is not. The thumbnail covers all the wrapper's height but not the width. I want the thumbnail to also maintain the aspect ratio of 9:16.

Also, I did not add a custom thumbnail.

```css
.potrait_9by16
   {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 177.777%; /* 9:16 Aspect Ratio*/
   }

.potrait_9by16 iframe 
  {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div className="potrait_9by16">
     <iframe            
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        frameborder="0"
        src={videoObject.src}
        allow="fullscreen"
     ></iframe>
</div>
```

[Here is an image of the wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc4qD.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
div.outer { overflow: hidden }
div.outer > div.inner { position: relative; margin: 0 -109.7283%; padding: 88.8888888% 0; overflow: hidden }
div.outer > div.inner > iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 }
</style>

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iDKGJXBszk2nI9h9BNG3rJ2zD85FSNy/preview">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It may mess up the video playback, though. The video controls (progress-bar etc.) get cropped when playback starts.

Replace the code there with the one I have provided.

---

I just checked your code, and looks like what you need is:

```
.x { overflow: hidden }
.neg { position: relative; margin: 0 -109.7283; padding: 88.8888888% 0 }
.neg > iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 }
```

and use only x class for outer div, only neg class for inner div. That should probably do it.

---

I thought about removing the negative margin on playback, and was experimenting with something along those lines, but didn't get around to completing it. It should work to some extent, but what I found was that the black bordered thumbnail may be displayed for a short time before the playback starts (at least the way I tried it). If that's Ok, you could try that method. What I thought of was to display an invisible div (transparent overlay) covering the iframe that can capture a click and switch the iframe src to autoplay=1 URL. See if you can get that to work. If I have some time, I may look further into that.

I was adding a div using JavaScript with the same style as the iframe, just after the iframe:

```
.overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 }
```

If this div is added last, it will already be topmost. Otherwise, use z-index.

Then handle the 'click' event on the div.

---

The above div overlay technique has it's limitations. The below technique may be better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Player</title>
    <div id="player"></div>
```

---

```
body { background: #efe; padding: 2em; color: #575 }
h1:first-child { margin-top: 0 }

.player, #player { overflow: hidden }
.player > div, #player > div { position: relative; padding: 88.88888% 0; overflow: hidden }
.player video, .player iframe,
#player video, #player iframe
{ position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 }
.player:not(.playing) > div, #player:not(.playing) > div
{ margin: 0 -109.7283% }
```

---

```
((W, D) => {
    let $ = a => document.getElementById(a)
    class Player {}
    Player.play = (id, url) => {
        let p = $(id)
            , f = D.createElement('iframe')
            , d = D.createElement('div')
        f.src = url
        f.setAttribute('frameborder', 0)
        f.height =
        f.width = '100%'
        f.addEventListener( 'mouseover', e => f.dataset.overMe = 1 )
        f.addEventListener( 'mouseout', e => delete f.dataset.overMe )
        W.addEventListener( 'blur', e => {
            if (f.dataset.overMe === '1')
                setTimeout(a => p.classList.add('playing'), 1000)
        } )
        p.innerHTML = ''
        d.appendChild(f)
        p.appendChild(d)
    }
    W.Player = Player
})(window, document);

Player.play('player', 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iDKGJXBszk2nI9h9BNG3rJ2zD85FSNy/preview')
```

See if you can use this latest update with multiple iframes...

Your issue could be because you may be using an id (maybe the same id) with all player divs. When using multiple player divs, you need to use unique ids and use class="player" for the divs instead of id="player":

```
<div id="player-1" class="player"></div>
<div id="player-2" class="player"></div>
<div id="player-3" class="player"></div>
```

If it still doesn't work, show me a demo (on your site, maybe), and I'll take a look. Call the play method with the id like

```
Player.play('player-1', 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iDKGJXBszk2nI9h9BNG3rJ2zD85FSNy/preview')
Player.play('player-2', 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iDKGJXBszk2nI9h9BNG3rJ2zD85FSNy/preview')
```

Comment: I'm using the exact same markup that you provided. The only difference is that the height and the width are inline in yours. I'm using a 9:16 potrait video from my google drive. When the video runs, it has no black bars and it maintains 9:16 aspect ratio.The only problem is with the thumbnail.

Comment: I meant that the height and width are set in the iframe tag. I copy pasted your exact code in my file. It is still the same. The thumbnail not mainting the 9:16 aspect ratio. Also, what does 'share your video player' mean? I'm using an <iframe> tag the src property set to 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/16iDKGJXBszk2nI9h9BNG3rJ2zD85FSNy/view?usp=sharing'. I guess, the player is youtube player. Try the tag with this link. See if you get the same problem and please inform me.Thanks

Comment: That's weird. When I click the google drive link, the thumbnail is the same aspect ratio as the video. Also, I checked the thumbnail image using google chrome dev tools and found the image dimensions to be 640x360 which is 16:9. So, the thumbnail itself is not the problem. Somehow the image of the thumbnail is getting stretched and distorted. I suspect the iframe is not supposed to play potrait videos like that. Can I somehow target the <img> tag that gets created in the browser? [continued below]

Comment: [continued] Also, I found out that when I click the play button the video, another play button appers (like the one you see on youtube) and the video is paused at 0:00 waiting to be played. At this moment, as there is no thumbnail and the video wrapper looks exactly like I want it to. I was wondering if I could click the 'white' play button programatically as the page loads. Also, you solution of the negative margin did not work. But, thanks for trying. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The whole thumbnail screen is 9:16 because when I play the video, there are no black bars and the video is 9:16. The thumbnail look stretched.

Comment: . When I tried your solution, the aspect ratio got distorted and it got back to landscape. I have deployed the website for you to see . The potrait videos are in a grid container with grid-template-columns set to repeat(3,1fr). The link to the website is [HERE](https://media-gallery-vedang.netlify.app/) . Go to Animals<My Pets<VIdeos.[continued below].

Comment: [continued] If you would like to look at the source code ,it is [HERE](https://github.com/Vedang-Danej/media-gallery)  . The relevant markup is in the IFrameSkleton.js file and the css in App.css.

Comment: Currently, the negative margin is applied to all the potrait iframes wrappers.

Comment: Sorry for not trying out in the editor. I wasn't wrapping the 9by16 wrapper with another div. The thumbnail now covers the whole video. Thanks a lot for that, I just have one problem now. The padding is now going all the way down and pushing the below content further down.Can you please provide a fix for that? Again, sorry for not correctly  following your code. You can see the bug [HERE](https://media-gallery-vedang.netlify.app). Animals<My Pets<Videos

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't thank you enough. I had lost all hope on this project after getting so frustated and annoyed. There's a last thing I would like to ask you. As you know, the playback is messed up. But, I only need the negative margin class before clicking the 'white' play button. I'm thinking to programatically remove the 'neg' class when I click the white play button. Will that work or you would suggest something else?

Comment: The autoplay=1 dosen't work with google drive videos. It only works with youtube videos. I was trying to catch a click on the neg class div but that wasn't working. I tried setting it's z-index to 100 , but that didn't work. Regarding the bordered thumbnail being shown for a little while before the playback starting , I could use the setTimeout function to wait a few milliseconds and then remove the neg class. I could try it. But first, I need to sucessfully catch a click on the iframe. Could you send me the markup of the transparent overlay that you experimented with?

Comment: Wow, this worked. I'm displaying multiple iframes in a grid system on the webpage. This solution works only for one iframe. Also, I'm using React.js for front end. I can attach onClick, onBlur etc on divs. When I tried to listen to the  the 'blur' event on the window object, It did not work for me consistently. Probably because I'm using react and it uses a virtual DOM. But I've got the general idea now. I will try implementing it in react and tell you if it's successful. Also, can I listen for the onBlur event on any other div other than the window object?

Comment: @infernus-85, I think onblur is supported on any Element, Document, or Window, but unless you use Window, it may not have the desired result, in this case.

Comment: I will experiment with it and see what results I can get. But, I'm happy with the thumbnail covering 100% of the container. I'm not going to have as many potrait videos in the website.And frankly, only I'm going to visit the website regularly. Thank you for all the help that you provided.

Comment: No, I just see one iframe even when I add three Player.play() functions. I think it's because you set p.inneHTML=' '. When I commented p.innerHTML=' ', I did see three players, but then the video played with the video controls messed up again.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. My PC broke and it took a while to fix. Anyways, your method works. Thanks a lot. I'm using React.js and I think someone made an Iframe click package using the approach you used. The link to the npm package is [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iframe-click). This custom element would be a lot easy for me to use. The only problem I'm having with it is that the <Iframe> element registers just one click on the first iframe I click and I have multiple iframes on a single page. When  I click somewhere else and bring the focus back to the page and then click (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) the iframe again, it registers a click again. So, I think I need to bring the focus back to the page after I register a click on every iframe. I've tried the focus() function on the window object but that dosen't work. I've also tried to register a click on the container of the iframe by using the click() method on the container but that dosen't work either. Do you have a solution for this. Basically, I want to brign the focus back to the page after I register a click on an <Iframe> element.

Comment: @infernus-85, I don't know if this will work for you, but you could try the blur() method on the iframe, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to implement the code you provided in JS to react.js and it worked. Thanks.